# Does a web application that has to be run via localhost need security?

Tags: php, web-applications, localhost

I've been working on making an RMS (Record Management System) a web based application that has a functionality of CRUD and it is intended to run via localhost that is operated only by one person (admin). The main question is that, is **SECURITY** necessary on the web app even though it is run via localhost only? If so, what scope should I look into and apply?

Comment: I would say yes. Just because it's meant to be used by one person now, maybe that can change? Either way, there might be others that will gain access to their system (either co-workers, viruses or similar). If the info is sensitive, then I would say it definitely is a must. We can't really give you a more specific answer since we don't know any specifics about the system or the usage of it. Defensive programming always wins.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well no not really, if it is just one person. But if you're talking about a localhost which can be accessed remotely through passwords then obviously you would need some sort of security to prevent bypassing of some sort.

But if you want to stay on the safe side of things then maybe just do it anyway because there's never a 0% risk of attack

Comment: That's a dangerous statement. If the computer is compromised in any way (someone else sitting by that computer or if someone hacks the computer/virus), the information/system would also be compromised.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Well of course you always need some sort of security but all I'm saying is don't go too overboard depending on the circumstances.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information for us to responsibly say anything other than a resounding "yes, you need security", imho. And what would be "overboard" in this case? I honestly don't think it matters if the system should be on localhost or not, just follow security best practices no matter what. Having extra security never hurts, but missing something definitely can.